# I am getting internal server serror 500 while making axios post request for stripe payment

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, stripe-payments

// pay.js >> stripe folder

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState , useEffect } from 'react';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import logo from "../images/logo.png";

const KEY = "pk_test_51Lo3qjSF....X4f1ze....";

const Pay = () => {

  const [stripeToken , setStripeToken] = useState(null);

  const onToken = (token) =>{
    setStripeToken(token);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try{
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payments" , {
          tokenId : stripeToken.id,
          amount : 2000
        });
        console.log(res.data);
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);     
      }
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  } , [stripeToken]);
```

// stripe.js >> api folder

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);

router.post("/payments", (req, res) => {
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      source: req.body.tokenId,
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "usd",
    },
    (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
      if (stripeErr) {
        res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

[this error I am getting ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLIIX.png

this is showing axios error what is axios error and how can I resolve this can you please help me

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Comment: chances are `req.body.tokenId` and `req.body.amount` are undefined since you dont' seem to be using a body parser in your express code

Comment: Can you log the `stripeErr` and show the full error? On the side note, [Charges and Tokens APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api) are legacy and no longer recommended as they don't support authentication. [PaymentIntent API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) is recommended.